# how to change a class variable array from outside the class?

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I need to change an array from outside the class, which is a class variable. For example see my code below:

```
<?php
class ArrayRet
{
    private $_ar = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_ar['test1'] = 'hello1';
        $this->_ar['test2'] = 'hello2';
    }

    public function getAr()
    {
        return $this->_ar;
    }

    public function dump()
    {
        var_dump($this->_ar);
    }
}

$arRet = new ArrayRet();
$arRet->dump();
$ar = $arRet->getAr();
$ar['test2'] = 'works!!!';
$arRet->dump();
?>
```

`$this->_ar['test2']` should be `works!!!` but it´s still `hello2`

How can I get this working?

Edit: With changing the syntax a bit as found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), it works. So, we need to change the method to this:

```
public function &getAr()
{
   return $this->_ar;
}
```

And also the call to this:

```
$ar = &$arRet->getAr();
```

Answer (score 2):

you made 2 mistake : 
1- you put your array in `$ar` and you changed it, so you changed `$ar`,Not `$arRet`, so your object Not changed.
2- you set `_ar` as private,so you can't change it directly, so you must make another function to change it. some thing like :

```
    <?php
    class ArrayRet
    {
        private $_ar = array();

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->_ar['test1'] = 'hello1';
            $this->_ar['test2'] = 'hello2';
        }

        public function getAr()
        {
            return $this->_ar;
        }
        public function dump()
        {
            var_dump($this->_ar);
        }
        public function change_var($key,$val)
        {
           $this->_ar[$key] = $val;
        }
    }

    $arRet = new ArrayRet();
    $arRet->dump();
    $arRet->change_var('test1','works!!!');
    $ar = $arRet->getAr();

    $arRet->dump();
var_dump($ar);
    ?>
```

as you see  `$arRet` changed and you put it into `$ar`.

Comment: as far as I know, if I return a class variable, I give a reference back to the caller. But PHP copies it. And `return &$this->_ar;` gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

With your current code you can't as you have declared the visibility of `ArrayRet::$_ar` to be `private` meaning it cannot be accessed outside the scope of the class.

By declaring `ArrayRet::$_ar` as `public` you can do the following...

```
class ArrayRet
{
    public $_ar = array();
    // ...
}

$arRet = new ArrayRet();
$arRet->_ar['test2'] = 'works!!!';
$arRet->dump();
```

I don't recommend directly modifying object properties from outside of the class as this can cause headaches.